# Is it possible to move an entire folder directory, while retaining the registration data and program data?

Tags: file, directory, location, registration

I was just on a site where someone was a little peeved because their program installer wouldn't allow them to install the program in a different location.  That location it installed was C:\

Is there a workaround for this?  Can I move all files and program data, such as a registration key from a promotional free license, to another location (Program Files x86).

I thought there was a way to do this, but I am not sure.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how the program was written.

For example if the program was written so that it load resources from an hardcoded directory like **C:\BadApp**. Moving it to **C:\Program Files** will fail as it will not function properly.

If you don't have access to the source the best way is to move the program to **C:\Program Files\BadApp** and create a symbolic link from **C:\BadApp** to **C:\Program Files**. It may work a little better.

Comment: How do I create a symbolic link?

Comment: If you are using NTFS , http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx